# Advanced Find and Replace Program

Tags: text-processing

I have code in which I need to do a mass find and replace (within only one file).

I need to do the following with over a hundred items:

Turn:

```
begin();
Random code in between.

begin();
More random code...

100 more "begin()"s...

begin();
```

Into:

```
begin(1);
Random code in between.

begin(2);
More random code.

100 more "begin()"s...

begin(102);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
perl -pe 's/begin\(/$&. ++$n/ge' < input-file
```

Or for in-place editing (that is replace the file with the modified copy of itself):

```
perl -pi.back -e 's/begin\(/$&. ++$n/ge' input-and-output-file
```

(remove the `.back` if you're feeling adventurous and don't need a backup).

The above replaces ever `begin(` with the same (`$&`) with the incremented value of the `$n` variable (`++$n`) appended (`.`).

If you want to replace `begin()` instead of `begin(`:

```
perl -pe 's/begin\(\K\)/++$n.")"/ge' < input-file
```

Comment: Thank you, but sorry, I'm confused, 1. What's in-place editing? 2. so how would I find and replace within the file "home/user/testing.txt".

Comment: @RandomPerson323 in-place editing means that instead of reading one file and writing to stdout, perl will edit the input file. The .back part makes a backup of the file with the extension .back. See `man perlrun` for more.

Comment: @derobert technically it doesn't edit in place, but it looks that way to the user.

Comment: @jordanm Indeed, it's actually done with a temp file and a rename, as documented in the man page.

Comment: Thank you, Now I get what in-place editing is. I just need to know like I said before: how would I find and replace within the file "home/user/testing.txt"

Comment: I will mark this answer as correc, once I get a reply.

Comment: @RandomPerson323, replace `input-and-output-file` with `home/user/testing.txt`.

Comment: Sorry, I though the "input-and-output-file" was some sort of commment :). This answer correctly solves my problem.